# How do I output Rich Text to a printable format from Laravel

Tags: laravel, trix

I have a Laravel application that allows users to build method statements. They can build rich text Method Statements using Laravel-Trix editor which allows the inclusion of images. All this works fine but I need to output the completed report to PDF, or at least some format that allows me to print the report.

I have tried FPDF, SnappyPDF, and DomPDF. DomPDF will output the formatted text but not the images.

Does anyone know how to achieve this. I don't have to use Trix but it is easy to use in Laravel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this package :
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy

Comment: @BKF No will not output trix image attachments.

Comment: @Finchy70 Hi mate, could you solve it? I also need to do that